# Rewriting URL on Dreamhost

Tags: .htaccess, rewrite

I am trying to rewrite a URL for a Dreamhost served website. So basically I want to do the following:

- Rewrite only URLs that start with an x!
- URLs like this http:// domain.com/x23 should be rewritten into into http:// domain.com/index.php/lookup/code/x23

Without showing the rewritten URL of course!

I tried this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(x[0-9a-z])$ index.php/lookup/code/$0 [L]
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

Thanks,
Max

Comment: You might want to ask this on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Thanks, just did I was confused wether it was a server or stackoverflow ?. :D

Answer (score 1):

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445937

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html) can help.